# Collaborative filtering

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

How can I use SVD algorithm in Mahout for producing recommendations on explicit binary data-set (e.g. a user purchased or not but no specific ratings) in an e-commerce domain? Also what algorithms aim at producing recommendations on such binary data-sets?

Answer (score 2):

You should post this question to the mahout-user mailing list.

See here http://mahout.apache.org/mailinglists.html

Comment: I sent it to the group also, but its not posted yet.I only see posts until may 2010.